# How do I open the "New Tab" page explicitly in Chrome from a Web Page?

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink, tabs

On typing `chrome://newtab` or `about:newtab` in Google Chrome's Address Bar, we can explicitly open a new tab.

How can we do the same from a Web Page ?

I tried it on a hyper-link, like `<a href="chrome://newtab" target="_blank">Click to open the Chrome's 'New Tab' page</a>`, but it doesn't work..

I even tried using JavaScript using `window.open('chrome://newtab','_newtab')` and redirection using `window.location = chrome://newtab`, neither worked..

Is there any way to achieve this from a Web page, like by clicking or redirecting to the newtab ?

Hope my question is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do to open a new tab, is open a blank page.

Colon's are required to open urls like `chrome:newtab`:

```
var win = window.open('http://chrome:newtab', '_blank');
```

but they are not allowed in any url:

> A colon is reserved and may not be used unencoded except for its
>   special purpose (which depends on the scheme). Section 2.2:
>
> Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning:
>   their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
>   designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
>   reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded. The characters ";",
>   "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
>   reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may
>   be reserved within a scheme.

Even if you try to encode it:

```
var win = window.open('http://chrome%3Anewtab', '_blank');
```

Chrome will not allow you to do that. You most likely already saw:

> Unable to open a window with invalid URL 'http://chrome:newtab/'.

Chrome will allow you to use colons, but only as parameters. Look at the example below, and note the question mark in the second url.

**rejected**

```
var win = window.open('http://something.com%3Apro', '_blank');
```

**permitted**

```
var win = window.open('http://something.com?%3Apro', '_blank');
```

Comment: @GokulNC To make up for the **** reading, I've done some reserach  for you.

Comment: Thanks, my question is how do I open `chrome://newtab` from a webpage.. How do I do it ??

Comment: @GokulNC As for what i've read and stated above, I don't consider it possible without a Chrome plugin. You could develop a chrome plugin that opens the *newtab* page if you open a *blank* page. But, obviously, that only works if it is a private project.

Answer (score 0):

In hyperlink, you need to put target="_blank" in the a balise.

Comment: That's not chrome only.

Comment: He said "I tried it on a hyper-link, like <a href="chrome://newtab" target="_blank"> New Tab </a>, but it doesn't work.."
<br /><br />
So in standard hyperlink, to have a new tab, _blank in target property is needed.

Comment: You want to open only a new tab, doesn't matter about browser or only in chrome?
"<a href="" target="_blank">Click to open the Chrome's 'New Tab' page</a>" With that, new tab in the default browser set on the system.

Comment: Change the link in the href? oO
When you said, it's openning the same page, which page?