# How to open a new browser tab with no URL (via onClick on webpage) as if you clicked the "+" button to add a new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How does one go about opening a new tab with no URL in the address bar via an onClick event from a webpage as if you clicked on the "+" button to the right of all the tabs.

Yes, I can do `onClick={() => window.open('', '_blank')}` to open a new tab without a URL. But that will result in `about:blank` appearing in the address bar. Something I don't want. The new tab that opens should be **exactly as if you clicked on the "+" button**.

JFYI, I'll also be okay if instead of a new tab opening, the page where the onClick originated from becomes the blank page. As if you clicked the home button.

Comment: on chrome is `chrome://newtab` , on other browsers i don't know if it's possible

Comment: How do you implement `chrome://newtab`? I did the following, `onClick={() => window.open('https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab', '_blank')}`. While it did open a new tab, the address bar was not blank.

Comment: `window.open('chrome://newtab', '_blank')` Check the user agent before

Comment: I just found another SO question just like mine from 3 years ago with no concrete answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596150/how-do-i-open-the-new-tab-page-explicitly-in-chrome-from-a-web-page

Comment: Gotcha. I'll give that a try. I have no idea what the user agent is but let me do some reading. As of now, when I execute `window.open('chrome://newtab', '_blank')` I see the following error in my console, `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://newtab/`. Does this have something to do with the user agent? Don't know but I'll investigate.

Comment: Ah.. then it won't work, sorry, haven't tested. Guess you're stuck with `about:blank` then :(

Comment: Dang. I really don't want to give up this easily. I'll look into this a bit more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Comment: I am also trying to do this, but from a Chrome extension popup in order to open my custom new tab. It's possible with the `tabs` permission and `chrome.tabs.create(...)`, but this causes my users to think I'm "reading all browser history" because of the permission scope.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to do what you want using available browser APIs. The syntax of `window.open` is `window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)`. The first 2 is what defines how this new "window" is opened. The url of where the window should go. This can be left as an empty string, but will open a window as "about:blank". The 2nd part is the name, which defines how the window should be open (tab, window, etc).

Local resources can't be loaded with this URL, so "chrome://newtab" won't work. Trying to use a period as your url will open the new window with whatever page the window was opened from. Trying to use a slash as the url will open the new window as the base path of where the new window was created from. Invalid urls that I tried (random strings and characters) will just open a new window with your current url, but also append whatever you typed.

From what it looks like, you're stuck with "about:blank", or having to look in to other options.

**Sources for reference**

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0):

about:newtab seems to work in chrome and Firefox but not in edge. While about:home works in Firefox and edge but not chrome. You could probably detect the web browser and act accordingly.

### Update:

Sorry, these pages appear to be privileged and cannot be acceded by other websites.

Answer (score -5):

**could you use any of these**

```
<a href="javascript:if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft Internet Explorer') != -1){location='http://facebook.com/';}if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Netscape') != -1){
window.open('http://facebook.com/','','width=600,height=400,left=50,top=50,toolbar=yes');};void 0">
New new window</a>

<input type="button" value="
New new window" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://facebook.com/','','width=600,height=400,left=50,top=50,toolbar=yes');" />
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm looking at here. What does facebook.com have to do with opening a new tab?